# (VHDL) signal <CLK_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal does not drive any load pins in the design

Tags: signals, vhdl

Hi awesome stackoverflow community,

I'm working on a project for my school and I have to switch on different leds one after another one to make a "rotating light" on a Xilinx Spartan3E-100.
Currently, my VHDL program works but with no clock so all the leds are switched on (too fast). When I try to add clock, I get the following error:

```
The signal <CLK_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal does not drive any load pins in the design.
```

Here's my VHDL code (edited):

```
  library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity test2 is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           S0 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           S1 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           S2 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           S3 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           S4 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           S5 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           S6 : out  STD_LOGIC);
end test2;

architecture Behavioral of test2 is
CONSTANT st0 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "000"; -- listing case for signal
CONSTANT st1 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "001";
CONSTANT st2 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "010";
CONSTANT st3 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "011";
CONSTANT st4 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "100";
CONSTANT st5 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "101";
CONSTANT st6 : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "110";
SIGNAL state : std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := "000";
BEGIN
    chenillard: PROCESS(CLK)
    BEGIN
        if (rising_edge(CLK)) then -- synchronise clock for the following case
        case state is
        when st0 => -- when signal is 000
        S0<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
        state<=st1; -- signal incrementation
        when st1 => -- when signal is 001
        S1<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
        state<=st2; -- signal incrementation
        when st2 => -- when signal is 010
        S2<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
        state<=st3; -- signal incrementation
        when st3 => -- when signal is 011
        S3<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
        state<=st4; -- signal incrementation
        when st4 => -- when signal is 100
        S4<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
        state<=st5; -- signal incrementation
        when st5 => -- when signal is 101
        S5<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
        state<=st6; -- signal incrementation
        when st6 => -- when signal is 110
        S6<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
        state<=st0; -- signal incrementation back to st0 for loop
        when others =>NULL;
        end case;
        end if;
    end process chenillard;
end Behavioral;
```

Here's my UCF file:

```
NET "CLK" LOC = "C8";
NET "S0" LOC= "M5";
NET "S1" LOC= "M11";
NET "S2" LOC= "P7";
NET "S3" LOC= "P6";
NET "S4" LOC= "N5";
NET "S5" LOC= "N4";
NET "S6" LOC= "P4";
```

I searched for answer on google but nothing that i found seems to work. thanks for help and sorry for my english, i'm not a native english speaker ;)

Comment: Try adding `CLK` to the process sensitivity list, and replacing `wait until CLK='1'` with `if (rising_edge(CLK)) then ... end if;`, where `...` is your existing case statement.

Comment: Also, how did you choose the port mode for CLK?

Comment: my bad @BrianDrummond i was just experimenting and forgot to erase inout when posting :) CLK is an in port. post edited. thanks for noticing

Comment: @scary_jeff i don't know how to add process.. i found something but not sure ;) by adding CLK to sensitivity list you mean adding CLK to the following line :   `chenillard: PROCESS(CLK)`  like this ? if so, i tried but got the same problem

Comment: @scary_jeff and the OP: I'm not sure if the old XST synthesizer for Spartan 3 FPGAs can handle `wait until ...` statements, because XST inferred an `IBUF` (normal input) but no `IBUFG` (clock input). Also your UCF file is missing the timing constraints for `CLK`.

Comment: Did you replace your `wait` statement with an `if (rising_edge(CLK)) then ...` statement like I suggested?

Comment: yes :
   `chenillard: PROCESS(CLK)
    BEGIN
  if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
  case state is
  ...
  end case;
  end if;
 end process chenillard;
end Behavioral;`
where ... is the statement case ( too long for a comment ;) )

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with your new code. I can't see that you've done anything wrong. Try a "Project" > "Clean Up Project Files" in ISE.

Comment: still the same error. also I updated my question with the code. I'll try to see this problem with my teacher. thanks a lot tho'

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it works ! I noticed the truth table created by the program was different from my theoretical truth table.
Here's the new truth table created by the program:
[Truth_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNwvC.png)

Here's how I fixed the problem:

```
if (rising_edge(CLK)) then -- synchronise clock for the following case
          case state is
        when st0 => -- when signal is 000
        S0<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
          S1<='0';
          S2<='0';
          S3<='0';
          S4<='0';
          S5<='0';
          S6<='0';
        state<=st1; -- signal incrementation
        when st1 => -- when signal is 001
        S1<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
          S0<='0';
          S2<='0';
          S3<='0';
          S4<='0';
          S5<='0';
          S6<='0';
        state<=st2; -- signal incrementation
        when st2 => -- when signal is 010
        S2<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
          S0<='0';
          S1<='0';
          S3<='0';
          S4<='0';
          S5<='0';
          S6<='0';
        state<=st3; -- signal incrementation
        when st3 => -- when signal is 011
        S3<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
          S0<='0';
          S1<='0';
          S2<='0';
          S4<='0';
          S5<='0';
          S6<='0';
        state<=st4; -- signal incrementation
        when st4 => -- when signal is 100
        S4<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
          S0<='0';
          S1<='0';
          S2<='0';
          S3<='0';
          S5<='0';
          S6<='0';
        state<=st5; -- signal incrementation
        when st5 => -- when signal is 101
        S5<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
          S0<='0';
          S1<='0';
          S2<='0';
          S3<='0';
          S4<='0';
          S6<='0';
        state<=st6; -- signal incrementation
        when st6 => -- when signal is 110
        S6<='1'; -- it will switch on a led.
          S0<='0';
          S1<='0';
          S2<='0';
          S3<='0';
          S4<='0';
          S5<='0';
        state<=st0; -- signal incrementation back to st0 for loop
        when others =>NULL;
        end case;
        end if;
    end process chenillard;
end Behavioral;
```

As you can see for each case I added every LEDs which are off and not only the one led which is on. Before doing this, when ISE process mapped, it told the clk_buf were incomplete because not all the possibility were listed.